# Throwing exception to client in GWT (Google Web Toolkit)

Tags: java, exception, gwt

I'm using GWT (currenly working with google's eclipse plugin), and I'm trying to throw an exception from the server to the client.

My exception is something like

```
class LoginException extends Exception implements IsSerializable
```

But I get (upon loading in hosted mode):

> [ERROR] Errors in '[...]/src/myPackage/client/services/Session.java'
>
> > [ERROR] Line 25: No source code is available for type hugobarrera.gestorAlumnos.server.LoginException; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Session.java is:
[...]

```
public interface Session extends RemoteService {
```

[...] (Line 25:)

```
String newSession(String usr, String pwd) throws LoginException;
```

[...]

Where am I going wrong? I've read like a MILLION places where people have problems with throwing exceptions, but none of those solutions applied.

Comment: Is LoginException in the same java package and project as the Session interface?

Comment: It wasn't. Moving it to the same package solved the problem. Also, moving it to [...]services.exceptions also works :) You should post this as an answer rather than a comment (=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All classes that need to be serialized must be in the [...].client package or a sub package.

<del>Apparently they may not have a constructor either.</del>
[edit] You need to have a no-argument constructor in the serializable classes.

Comment: *WRONG* all classes have a constructor, you cant compile one without. GWT requires a no arguments constructor which doesnt have to be public.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was the conclusion I'd made. I fixed the answer now :) Note that you CAN'T not-have a constructor, if you don't define any, the no-arg constructor is implicitly defined.

Comment: "If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor that takes no parameters is automatically provided[...]"   
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.9   More info(Actual source of link): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525548/default-constructors-and-inheritance-in-java

Answer (score 2):

skaffman: LoginException was not in the same package as Session.

Hugo: Moving them to the same package solved the problem.