# Should I call super() when overriding AsyncTask's constructor?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, overriding

In many examples I have seen online, `AsyncTask` is extended, the constructor is overriden, and super() isn't called. For example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3359003/312499) by hackbod:

```
static class Worker extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    MyActivity mActivity;

    Worker(MyActivity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    [...]

}
```

the new constructor does not call back to the parent's constructor.

There's similar code in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java) by CommonsWare.

So is this correct? Or should `super()` really be called?

Comment: Take a look at the constructor of ASyncTask and see if this is something you want to use: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The default super constructor is called implicitly if super() is not called explicitly. So there is really no difference at all. I'd use the shorter version (omit super()), which seems to be common practice in Java.

p.s. See also this thread: [Default constructors and inheritance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525548/default-constructors-and-inheritance-in-java)

Comment: so ok, i need to improve my english to use more specific words... >/

Comment: @Stefan, FYI many methods in the Android framework will throw an error if you have not called super explicitly, such as in `onCreate` (providing rationale for the question)

Comment: @KristopherMicinski super() or a super constructor that takes additional parameters? There should be only a difference if there is an alternative super constructor with parameters.

Comment: I am not speaking wrt constructors, but methods.  Anyway, I'm not contesting your answer, just trying to provide rationale for why it was asked.