# OOP Initializing instance variables with instances of child class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, null-object-pattern

I am trying to implement the NullObject design pattern on my class `Node`:

```
    class Node{
        Node nextNode;
        char key;
        Node prevNode;

        /* 
           Would like to initialize nextNode and prevNode to instance of 
           NullNode, something like this (I know what I am doing is wrong)
        */
        Node() {
            nextNode = new NullNode();
            prevNode = new NullNode();
        }
    }

    class NullNode extends Node {
         ....
    }
```

With this code I get a StackOverflowError Exception. How can I tackle this issue?

Comment: Have you heard of the `super` keyord? You can call the super-constructor `super()`.

Comment: What you are doing does not look wrong to me, you just have to override the constructor in `NullNode` to avoid endless recursion.

Comment: Right now I am getting StackOverflowError Exception

Comment: @fab How to override the constructor in NullNode?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a **StackOverflow** because the parent constructor is always called (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/527069/664108). In your case this results in endless recursion.

To avoid that, you will have to add a check in the `Node` constructor and call it explicitly from the `NullNode` constructor:

```
public class Node
{
    Node nextNode;
    char key;
    Node prevNode;

    Node() {
        Node(true);
    }
    Node(boolean createNullNodes) {
        if (createNullNodes) {
            nextNode = new NullNode();
            prevNode = new NullNode();
        }
    }
}

public class NullNode extends Node
{
    NullNode() {
        super(false);
    }
}
```

A better solution for the NullObject pattern is using interfaces. This eliminates the constructor problem and also allows to remove the not needed `nextNode` and `prevNode` variables from the `NullNode`.

**Example with interface:**

```
public interface INode
{
    public char getKey();
    public INode getNext();
    public INode getPrev();
    // ...
}

public class Node implements INode
{
    Node nextNode;
    char key;
    Node prevNode;

    Node() {
        nextNode = new NullNode();
        prevNode = new NullNode();
    }
    public char getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public INode getNext() {
        return nextNode;
    }
    public INode getPrev() {
        return prevNode;
    }
}

public class NullNode implements INode
{
    public char getKey() {
        return null;
    }
    public INode getNext() {
        return this;
    }
    public INode getPrev() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting stackoverflow..even after putting empty constructor in nullnode.

Comment: Sorry, I had a misconception there. Updated the answer with alternative solution.

Comment: I tried your above mentioned solution by Node() {Node(true); } and Node(boolean createNullNodes) {...} constructors..but getting an error at Node() {Node(true); } as the "The method Node(boolean) is undefined for the type Node"

Answer (score 0):

Normally we do not reference the `Subclass` in the `Suerclass`, this somehow breaks the inheritance relation.

In your code there is something even worse that will cause a `StackoverflowException` because the `superclass` creates an object with the `default constructor` of the `subclass` which in turns calls the default constructor of the `superclass` and it will go infinitely until your program crashes.

You can see an implementation of the *Null Object Pattern* [here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object/java-0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public clas Node
    {
        Node nextNode;
    char key;
    Node prevNode;

    Node() {
        this(true);
    }
    Node(boolean createNullNodes) {
        if (createNullNodes) {
            nextNode = new NullNode();
            prevNode = new NullNode();
        }

    }
}

    public class NullNode extends Node
    {
        NullNode() {
            super(false);
        }
    }
```

To call one constructor from another constructor use this(args)... you cannot call it directly